# Java DecimalFormat how it works

Tags: java, spring, locale, decimalformat

I have Java webservice code deployed on On-prem server where it uses IBM websphere as a application server. To display the currency in amount I am using below code. As output below code works as expected and display $123.00 BUT if i deploy same code on Cloud Kubernetes container  then amount value shows like this XXX123.00. It looks like on cloud container currency `$` is getting replaced with `XXX`. I want to know how `DecimalFormat` in Java works? Does it uses the locale of the machine?

```
public static  DecimalFormat CURRENCY_FORMAT = null;
    public static final String OPEN_BRACE = "(";
    public static final String CLOSE_BRACE = ")";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CURRENCY_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("##,###,##0.00");
        CURRENCY_FORMAT.setNegativePrefix(OPEN_BRACE
                + CURRENCY_FORMAT.getCurrency().getSymbol());
        CURRENCY_FORMAT.setNegativeSuffix(CLOSE_BRACE);
        CURRENCY_FORMAT.setPositivePrefix(CURRENCY_FORMAT.getCurrency().getSymbol());

        System.out.println(CURRENCY_FORMAT.format(123.00));
    }
```

Comment: From [`NumberFormat::getCurrency`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrency()): "*Gets the currency used by this number format when formatting currency values. **The initial value is derived in a locale dependent way.** ...*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its based on the locale.
You can change the locale as VM Parameter:

```
java -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
```

Or you can set it in your application with

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Andreas - Thanks, i was able to put above in my deployment.yaml. and it works !!!